# Please explain me what this writing actually means in examples?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, hook

> If nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must return the value
>   returned by CallNextHookEx.
>
> If nCode is greater than or equal to zero, and the hook procedure did
>   not process the message, it is highly recommended that you call
>   CallNextHookEx and return the value it returns; otherwise, other
>   applications that have installed WH_MOUSE hooks will not receive hook
>   notifications and may behave incorrectly as a result. If the hook
>   procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero value to
>   prevent the system from passing the message to the target window
>   procedure.

I find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644988%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and I am no good at English as well as this hooking stuff but I must do it as required. If you could explain me what it actually means with simple examples, I am really thankful. Please help me.... Thank you

Answer (score 4):

In pseudocode it means approx this:

```
if (nCode < 0) return CallNextHookEx();
else if (nCode >= 0 && !MsgProcessed) return CallNextHookEx();
else
     return 1;
```

Comment: You don't need to verify `nCode>=0` in the second `if`, if that condition was not met, then the previous `if` would `return` out of the function.